# Error: invalid_client from google+ quick start app for php

Tags: php, google-plus

What am I doing wrong with the google+  quickstart app? I think I followed the instructions well ( https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php ).  I am using a Mac OS 10.8, php ver 5.3.15.
When I click on the sign in button the popup has the error

> Error: invalid_client and the Request Details.

Notice the client_id value below and note that on the index.html page in my browser the title displays as {{ APLICATION_NAME }}:

Request Details

```
response_type=code token id_token gsession
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
redirect_uri=postmessage
access_type=offline
cookie_policy=single_host_origin
proxy=oauth2relay2033209164
origin=http://localhost
state=2128268783|0.3526941802619493
client_id={{ CLIENT_ID }}
request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity
authuser=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did,
1)renamed  the index.html to index.php
2) added `

```
const CLIENT_ID = '123###.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const APPLICATION_NAME = "Google+ PHP Quickstart";


?>`  to index.php top.
```

3) changed `{{    APPLICATION_NAME }}`  to `<?php echo  APPLICATION_NAME; ?>`  and ditto for CLIENT_ID 
4) in ...src/config.php I added the CLIENT_ID, APPLICATION_NAME and  CLIENT_SECRET values  to the $apiConfig array initializer thought that probably doesn't matter.

Now the example seems to work.  I still don't know what the deal is with those double curly braces.

Anyone have any light to shine on this please do so but I guess for now it's resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing as you. The page actually says to go to signin.php in your browser, not the root (index.html). This will parse the {{ XX }} vars correctly for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your default page: index.html change the title to your application name: `<title>LiveApp</title>`. In the body tag under the button class replace

`data-clientId={{ CLIENT_ID }}` with  `data-clientId="xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"` your client id. Your obviously must have filled in: `CLIENT_ID`, `APPLICATION_NAME` and ´CLIENT_SECRET`in the`signin.php`. Try to run your application it should work. That's what worked for me. Good luck :)